# Build database with .sql file with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, replication

Ok, i have searched high and low and have been unable to find an answer that works for what i am trying to do.  I have two databases, we'll call them DB1 and DB2.  I have a cron job that runs every night at 4am that backs up DB1 and stores its data in a SQL file archive, we'll call this file db_backup.sql.  The file is stored in a folder on the server, we'll call it ROOT/backups/db_backup.sql.

**Info**

```
database names: DB1 and DB2
backup filename: db_backup.sql
backup file path: ROOT/backups/db_backup.sql
```

**What i'm trying to do:**

I want to use the db_backup.sql file to build DB2.  I am basically trying to set up database replication where i replicate DB1 out to DB2.  Don't know of any other way to do this on shared hosting servers than what i'm trying to explain.  I am trying to use php to import the db_backup.sql file into DB2.

**My Environment:**

The website and databases are on a shared hosting account with godaddy (yes, i would love to get dedicated servers to set up real replication, but can't afford it for now).  The databases are mysql in phpmyadmin.

Is this something that is possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Let me know if you have any questions as well.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem.  You need to copy the db_backup file to the second host where you have access to the database and load the sql file.

From a shell:

```
mysql -hhost -uusername -ppassword databasename < db_backup.sql
```

This will restore the tables on the second machine.

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as, setting up a CRON job on server 2 to call a script on Server 1 which dishes out the SQL file, then that cron job script would import / rebuild the DB.

Make sure to require a hash (via get or post) before giving out the DB SQL on server 1, or else anyone could read it / have your database dump.

Comment: yea, i know the concepts of what i need to do...but don't really know the code to actually do it.  I'm very knew (like a week or so) to cron jobs and this sort of stuff.  Also, how do i require the hash (haven't done anything like that either? (haven't really needed to till now)

Answer (score 0):

Can you not avoid PHP altogether and connect directly to the database remotely to perform the backup either via the command line or using a scripting language more suitable for long running processes?